# Select Only the row with smallest id

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

suppose I have the following table X:

```
Id  Type  Name
1   1   Jane
2   2   Mary
3   3   Rose
4   4   Rachel
5   4   Darren
6   4   Jay
```

What will be the select statement to generate:

```
Id  Type  Name
1   1   Jane
2   2   Mary
3   3   Rose
4   4   Rachel
```

that only the first row for each type will be selected? Appreciate a lot.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.type = t.type);
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f2afb/13) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 SELECT t.* FROM test t
 INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id FROM test GROUP BY TYPE) t2 ON  t.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `row_number()` analytic function if your database supports it.

```
SELECT Id
    ,Type
    ,Name
FROM (
    SELECT X.*
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY type ORDER BY Id
            ) rn
    FROM X
    ) a
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c22a2e/9)